# python - replace last n columns with sum of all files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I am novice in python.

I have 8 csv files with 26 columns and 600 rows in each. now I want to take the last 4 column of each csv files (Column 22 to column 25), read the files and sum them up to replace all the 4 columns in each file. for example (I am showing some random data here):

new-1.csv:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
```

new2.csv:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k
11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11
12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  13
14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14
15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15
16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  16
17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17
18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  18
19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  19
```

Now, I want to sum each element of "h, i, j, k" of from these 2 files, then replace the files last 4 columns with this new sum.

Modified new-1.csv:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   12  12  12  12
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   14  14  14  14
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   16  16  16  16
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   18  18  18  18
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   20  20  20  20
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   22  22  22  22
7   7   7   7   7   7   7   24  24  24  24
8   8   8   8   8   8   8   26  26  26  26
9   9   9   9   9   9   9   28  28  28  28
```

Modified new-2.csv:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k
11  11  11  11  11  11  11  12  12  12  12
12  12  12  12  12  12  12  14  14  14  14
13  13  13  13  13  13  13  16  16  16  16
14  14  14  14  14  14  14  18  18  18  18
15  15  15  15  15  15  15  20  20  20  20
16  16  16  16  16  16  16  22  22  22  22
17  17  17  17  17  17  17  24  24  24  24
18  18  18  18  18  18  18  26  26  26  26
19  19  19  19  19  19  19  28  28  28  28
```

I am assuming I should use Panda or numpy for this, but not sure how to do it. any suggestions/hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this by just using numpy.**

```
import numpy as np

# list of all the files

file_list = ['foo.csv','bar.csv','baz.csv'] # all 8 files

col_names = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] # all the names till z if necessary as the first row, else skip this

# initializing a numpy array, for containing sum from last 4 columns

add_cols = np.zeros((600,4))

# iterating over all .csv files

for file in file_list :

    # skiprows will skip the first row and usecols will get values in last 4 cols

    temp = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=1, delimiter=',' , usecols = (22,23,24,25) )
    add_cols = np.add(temp,add_cols)

# now again overwriting all the files, substituting the last 4 columns with the sum   

for file in file_list :

    #loading the content from file in temp

    temp = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
    temp[:,[22,23,24,25]] = add_cols 

    # writing the column names first

    with open(file,'w') as p:
        p.write(','.join(col_names)+'\n')

    # now appending final values in temp to the file as csv

    with open(file,'a')  as p:  
        np.savetxt(p,temp,delimiter=",",fmt="%i")
```

Now if your file is not comma separated and rather space separated, remove the `delimiter` option from all the functions as the delimiter is taken as `space` by default. Also join the first column accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

After loading your csvs using `read_csv`, you can add the last 4 columns together and then overwrite them:

```
In [10]:
total = df[df.columns[-4:]].values + df1[df1.columns[-4:]].values
total

Out[10]:
array([[12, 12, 12, 12],
       [14, 14, 14, 14],
       [16, 16, 16, 16],
       [18, 18, 18, 18],
       [20, 20, 20, 20],
       [22, 22, 22, 22],
       [24, 24, 24, 24],
       [26, 26, 26, 26],
       [28, 28, 28, 28]], dtype=int64)

In [12]:    
df[df.columns[-4:]] = total
df1[df1.columns[-4:]] = total
df

Out[12]:
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g   h   i   j   k
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  12  12  12  12
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  14  14  14  14
2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  16  16  16  16
3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  18  18  18  18
4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  20  20  20  20
5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  22  22  22  22
6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  24  24  24  24
7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  26  26  26  26
8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  28  28  28  28

In [13]:    
df1

Out[13]:
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k
0  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  12  12  12  12
1  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  14  14  14  14
2  13  13  13  13  13  13  13  16  16  16  16
3  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  18  18  18  18
4  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  20  20  20  20
5  16  16  16  16  16  16  16  22  22  22  22
6  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  24  24  24  24
7  18  18  18  18  18  18  18  26  26  26  26
8  19  19  19  19  19  19  19  28  28  28  28
```

We need to call the attribute `.values` here to return a np array because otherwise it will try to align on the index which in this case do not align.

Once you overwrite them call `df.to_csv(file_path)` and `df1.to_csv(file_path)`

In the case of your 8 dfs you can loop over them and aggregate whilst looping:

```
# take a copy of the firt df's last 4 columns
total = df_list[0]
total = total[total.columns[-4:]].values
for df in df_list[1:]:
    total += df[df.columns[-4:]].values
```

Then just loop over your dfs again to overwrite:

```
for df in df_list:
    df[df.columns[-4:]] = total
```

And then write out again using `to_csv`.